# Markdown to Html in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node app. I'm trying to load some markdown files and convert them to HTML. I've seen some packages, yet, I'm not sure what I *should* use. I'm want to load the markdown and do some conversions before I get the HTML. I've been looking at [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) and [remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable). Unfortunately, I've had problems with markdown-js and it seems like its been orphaned. remarkable doesn't seem like I have the ability to do conversions like I'd like. For example, I'd like to change all h1 tags to h3 tags.

Does anyone have experience converting markdown to html and can recommend a package for this?

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you want to convert markdown to a non-standard HTML equivalent? For example, you want "# Hello" to convert to "<h3>Hello</h3>". Is that right?

Comment: @James - You are correct. I wouldn't say it's non-standard though. Rather, I'm trying to get some markup to work correctly within the bounds of a template.

Comment: You could use the cheerio module to modify the HTML heading tags once the markdown has been converted to HTML. I don't know of any markdown converters that provide what you're looking for directly.

Comment: @james It looks like markdown-js returns the markdown in an internmediate representation known as JSONML. I haven't been able to figure out how to parse it though.

Comment: @user70192 Why not generating a standard html code than replace ``h1`` with ``h3`` using regex or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js)
and it is working perfectly for my cases.
As i can understand from your question you want to convert **markdown** to **html** and also change all `h1` to `h3`, you can achieve that by :

- Convert `markdown` to `html`
- Change `h1` to `h3`

Here is an example that implements the previous simple algorithm :

```
var markdown = require( "markdown" ).markdown;
var markdownStr = ['#Hello World','somethig else','#another title'].join("\n");



var htmlResult= markdown.toHTML(markdownStr);


var finalResult = htmlResult.replace(/<h1>/g,'<h3>')
                            .replace(/<\/h1>/g,'</h3>');


console.log(htmlResult);    
console.log(finalResult); // <h3>Hello World</h3>
                          // <p>somethig else</p>
                          // <h3>another title</h3>
```

Now `finalResult` is holding the desired result.

You can check this [online demo](http://requirebin.com/?gist=6b826618ac8bc21a30aaa6c4d648da40)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for sharing your answer. I thought markdown-js allowed you to get an intermediate representation called JSONML. I wanted to modify that representation to ensure accuracy. My markdown has code in it. So, a global replace of <h1> won't work in my scenario.

Comment: @user70192 You can replace ``h1`` to ``h3`` at the end, once you are sure that all of  your code is executed.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "replace"? Do you mean replace like you're showing above using a string replace? Or, do you mean doing a replace by iterating through the intermediate representation. Once again, doing a string replace won't work because my markdown has code in it. Yet, I can't figure out how to iterate through the intermediate repsentation and update it that way.

Comment: @user70192 Your markdown that has code in it, assume it is executed at some point right, once you are sure your code(the one within your markdown) is executed and completed then your can perform your replace operation( using the proposed technique or something else).